# Override a CMake function twice

Tags: cmake, function-interposition

I have a CMake include file that overrides the built-in `add_executable` function, and I would like to figure out a way to do so transparently, so that if another file includes this file, but then also overrides `add_executable`, it will behave just as if they were interacting with the real `add_executable`. Here's a minimal CMakeLists.txt that demonstrates this problem.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)
project(interposition LANGUAGES C)

function(add_executable)
    message(STATUS "Inside of ${CMAKE_CURRENT_FUNCTION}")
    _add_executable(${ARGV})
endfunction()

function(add_executable)
    message(STATUS "Inside of the second copy of ${CMAKE_CURRENT_FUNCTION}")
    _add_executable(${ARGV})
endfunction()

add_executable(main main.c)
```

The idea of writing it this way is that each `_add_executable` symbol would refer to the previous definition of `add_executable`. In reality, this causes it to enter an infinite loop, where the first version of the function calls itself:

```
-- Inside of the second copy of add_executable
-- Inside of add_executable
-- Inside of add_executable
-- Inside of add_executable
...
```

If I change the first function to call `__add_executable()` (with two underscores), it says this:

```
-- Inside of the second copy of add_executable
-- Inside of add_executable
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:6 (__add_executable):
  Unknown CMake command "__add_executable".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:11 (_add_executable)
  CMakeLists.txt:14 (add_executable)
```

If I rename the first function to `_add_executable()` and also call the two-underscore version, then it doesn't even get called:

```
-- Inside of the second copy of add_executable
-- Configuring done
```

Here's the one I most expected might work (change `_add_executable()` to `cmake_language(CALL ...)`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)
project(interposition LANGUAGES C)

function(add_executable)
    message(STATUS "Inside of ${CMAKE_CURRENT_FUNCTION}")
    cmake_language(CALL _${CMAKE_CURRENT_FUNCTION} ${ARGV})
endfunction()

function(add_executable)
    message(STATUS "Inside of the second copy of ${CMAKE_CURRENT_FUNCTION}")
    cmake_language(CALL _${CMAKE_CURRENT_FUNCTION} ${ARGV})
endfunction()

add_executable(main main.c)
```

In reality, this enters the same infinite loop as the original example.

The closest I've gotten to something that works is to rename the prefix the second function with a single underscore, and call the double-underscore version within it, but this means that the functions call each other in the wrong order, and throws out the window the idea of making this work transparently.

Is there any way to make this work so that

1. The second copy of the function calls the first copy AND
2. The second copy doesn't need to know of the existence of the first copy?

Comment: As far as I know, CMake doesn't support overwriting the functions twice or more. Moreover, even a single overwriting is discouraged.

Comment: `even a single overwriting is discouraged` do you happen to have a citation for that?

Comment: E.g. [that post](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/23482#note_1183174) in a bugreport discussion:  "What I meant is that, when one finds a need to override a command, one should come to upstream to discuss a way to support the use case without an override.". BTW, the [post above](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/23482#note_1182840) suggests to consider using `cmake_language(DEFER)` instead of a function's overriding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Tsyvarev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3440745/tsyvarev) for pointing me in the right direction. His links led me to [this](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/23482) thread, explaining that the feature is unsupported, and never intended to exist, as well as [this](https://crascit.com/2018/09/14/do-not-redefine-cmake-commands/) article by Craig Scott, which confirms that multiple overrides will make the real function inaccessible.

It's a very unsatisfying answer, but it's helpful to know that that's the official stance of the CMake developers.